# when user type abc xyz then show it as abc#xyz on screen

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which i need to implement that whenever user hit the button it should appear as # on screen.
e.g PHP Android iOS will appear as PHP#Android#iOS

Comment: provide some more information about your question.

Comment: you want to set as text of that button?

Comment: i have an edit text named as tags in which we need to put the values so all i want is whenever user types and press space button then it will show it as #

Comment: as i mentioned above that if i write php and then press spac button to write another word like android then it should appear as PHP#Android

Comment: see `android.text.InputFilter` API documentation

Comment: handle editext on text change listner and check word and replace space with #.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way.

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {  }                                         
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

      String result = s.toString().replaceAll(" ", "#");
        if (!s.toString().equals(result)) {
             ed.setText(result);
             ed.setSelection(result.length());           
        }
        }
      });
```

Comment: `android.text.InputFilter` should be used for cases like this one, not `TextWatcher`